# Creating Web Service Descriptor(Consumer) in webMethods using HTTPS URL

Tags: web-services, ssl, truststore, webmethods

I have been trying to create a Web Service Consumer in my webMethods Integration Server to a certificate protected webservice, but when I try to do so using the Web Service Descriptor wizard, using HTTPS link after few seconds I get timeout:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

What I have done beforehand:

I have added the keystore to both my local Designer(config.ini):

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C\:\\keystore\\store.jks 
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
```

and I have also added a truststore with a certificate in my Integration Server using this guide:
    https://webmethodsexpert.com/2014/12/09/createmanage-keystore-and-truststore/

Certificate and connection itself is fine, using wget and the same certificate I managed to download the WSDL file(using HTTPS link).

I have also tried creating the Descriptor using the downloaded WSDL, but it contains:

```
 <wsdl:import namespace="http://xxx.xxx/" location="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

So it tries to connect to that location aswell. Note that the location link in that WSDL starts with "http", and port 80 to that site is blocked (only 443 HTTPS connection is open), which in result gives me following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://xxx.xxx/" location="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?wsdl=wsdl0
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to open the WSDL url in any browser and save it with .wsdl extension.
Using this .wsdl file webservice descriptor can be created.

*For the error `Connection timed out: connect` try changing network settings between native/direct/manual in Eclipse->Preferences->Network Settings.
There is also SSH settings that can be configured.